# iOS RealityKit. Changing Entity's translation causes unexpected behaviour

Tags: swift, arkit, realitykit

I am trying to create some AR experience.

I load the **Model** with animations as an **Entity**. Lets call it a **Toy**.
I create an **AnchorEntity**.
I attach the Toy to the **AnchorEntity**. Up to this point everything works great.

I want the **Toy** to walk in random directions. And it does for the first time. Then it gets interesting, allow me to share my code:

First method uses a newly created **Transform** for the **Toy** with the modified translation **x**, **y**, to make the **Toy** move and that is it.

```swift
func walk(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
        guard let robot = robot else {
            return
        }
        let currentTransform = robot.transform
        guard let path = randomPath(from: currentTransform) else {
            return
        }
        let (newTranslation , travelTime) = path
        
        let newTransform = Transform(scale: currentTransform.scale,
                                     rotation: currentTransform.rotation,
                                     translation: newTranslation)
        
        robot.move(to: newTransform, relativeTo: nil, duration: travelTime)

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + travelTime + 1) {
            completion()
        }
    }
```

We get that new **Transform** from the method below.

```swift
func randomPath(from currentTransform: Transform) -> (SIMD3<Float>, TimeInterval)? {
        // Get the robot's current transform and translation
        let robotTranslation = currentTransform.translation
        
        // Generate random distances for a model to cross, relative to origin
        let randomXTranslation = Float.random(in: 0.1...0.4) * [-1.0,1.0].randomElement()!
        let randomZTranslation = Float.random(in: 0.1...0.4) * [-1.0,1.0].randomElement()!
        
        // Create a translation relative to the current transform
        let relativeXTranslation = robotTranslation.x + randomXTranslation
        let relativeZTranslation = robotTranslation.z + randomZTranslation
        
        // Find a path
        var path = (randomXTranslation * randomXTranslation + randomZTranslation * randomZTranslation).squareRoot()
        
        // Path only positive
        if path < 0 { path = -path }
        
        // Calculate the time of walking based on the distance and default speed
        let timeOfWalking: Float = path / settings.robotSpeed

        // Based on old trasnlation calculate the new one
        let newTranslation: SIMD3<Float> = [relativeXTranslation,
                                            Float(0),
                                            relativeZTranslation]
        
        return (newTranslation, TimeInterval(timeOfWalking))
    }
```

The problem is that the value of **Entity.transform.translation.y** grows from 0 to some random value < 1. Always after the second time the **walk()** method is being called.

As you can see, every time the method is called, newTranslation sets the Y value to be 0. And yet the Toy's translation:
[image]

I am out of ideas any help is appreciated. I can share the whole code if needed.

Answer (score 2):

I have managed to fix the issue by specifying parameter **relativeTo** as Toy's AnchorEntity:

```swift
toy.move(to: newTransform, relativeTo: anchorEntity, duration: travelTime)
```